# Find sum of second values in key/value pair

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

just started with PySpark

I have a key/value pair like following `(key,(value1,value2))`

I'd like to find a sum of **value2** for each key

example of input data

```
 (22, (33, 17.0)),(22, (34, 15.0)),(20, (3, 5.5)),(20, (11, 0.0))
```

Thanks !

Comment: I tried       sumCount = rdd.map(lambda (x, (a, b)): b).sum() , but it doesn't contain the key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I created a new RDD contains key,value2 only , then just sum values of the new RDD

```
sumRdd = rdd.map(lambda (x, (a, b)): (x, b))\
.groupByKey().mapValues(sum).collect()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to benefit from combiner this would be a better choice.

```
from operator import add
sumRdd = rdd.map(lambda (x, (a, b)): (x, b)).reduceByKey(add)
```

Comment: Is it faster ? or less comuting ?

Comment: reduceByKey is better than groupByKey as it does map side combine.
https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html

Comment: Thanks @Knight71 , I've read about it , but forgot :) I'll take into account !